# How can I define a type based on a key in Record<K, T> in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I want to construct an object type and map the type to the specific key provided in `Record<Keys, Type>`.

For example, I have a type `User` which can be one of 3 strings - user, admin or moderator.
I want to have a type Stats that has different properties for each.

Doing so with a union type does not result in what I need:

```
type UserStats = {
  timeOnline: string;
};
type AdminStats = {
  timeAdmining: string;
};
type ModeratorStats = {
  timeModerating: string;
};
type User = 'USER' | 'ADMIN' | 'MODERATOR';

type Stats = Record<User, UserStats | AdminStats | ModeratorStats>;
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you really need a `Record` here? This record has a max length of 3, why not hardcode it as `interface Stats = {"USER": UserStats, "ADMIN": AdminStats, "MODERATOR": ModeratorStats}`?

Comment: And you could make fields optional if they may not be defined, e.g., `"USER"?: UserStats`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the opposite, i.e. derive `User` from `Stats` to avoid repeating yourself:

```
type UserStats = {
  timeOnline: string;
};
type AdminStats = {
  timeAdmining: string;
};
type ModeratorStats = {
  timeModerating: string;
};

type User = keyof Stats;

type Stats = {
    USER: UserStats;
    ADMIN: AdminStats;
    MODERATOR: ModeratorStats;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the changes as like bellow mentioned

**Replace :**

type Stats = Record<User, UserStats | AdminStats | ModeratorStats>;

**With :**

```
const Stats : Record<User, UserStats | AdminStats | ModeratorStats>={
      USER:{timeOnline:"User"},
      ADMIN:{timeAdmining:"Admin"},
      MODERATOR:{timeModerating:"Moderator"}
    };
    
    console.log(Stats.ADMIN);
```